# Application-defined error when trying to consolidate table data

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to use several workarounds and other posts, but cannot seem to find a way to answer the error I am having.

I am using Excel 2013 and am trying to grab information from a table to consolidate it. I also tried to copy the table data onto another worksheet, hoping that this would make it easier to consolidate. However, I am still having the same error above.

Ideally, I would like to grab the filtered table information and consolidate it. The reason it needs to be consolidated is that it will have multiple values for state in the table and I need to see the sum of a few categories based off of state (and other variables).

Please help me figure out why the code keeps on breaking at the consolidate piece of the code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim Issuer As String
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyArray As Variant

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("ChartData")
Issuer = ws2.Range("IssuerNum").Value

'Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

If Issuer = "All" Then
    Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    FirstRow = ws1.Cells(2, 1).Row

Else
    ws1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:=Issuer, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    With ws1.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
         LastRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Row + .Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count - 1
    End With
    FirstRow = ws1.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Row

End If

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(FirstRow, 3), ws1.Cells(LastRow, 9)).Select

Set MyArray = Selection

'Add in consolidate here to set up chart data
If ws2.Range("RadioSel").Value = 1 Then
ws2.Range("A2").Consolidate _
Sources:=MyArray.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
Function:=xlSum, LeftColumn:=True

End Sub()
```

Comment: What is giving you the error? The commented out line towards the top?

Comment: The line that gives the error is the consolidate step at the very end. It reads and starts the IF statement, but the ws2.Range("A2") etc does not work. It gives me the object-defined or application-defined error

Comment: Have you tried adding `External:=True` to the call to [Range.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: Thank you, barrowc! That solved the issue. Could you help me understand what the external:=true is doing? I have never seen that before.